# Sass @use not loading partial

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to import a sass partial (`_variables.scss`) to use in my main stylesheet (`global.scss`), but I keep getting the `Error: Undefined variable.` on sass compiling.

Directory structure:

```
app
└─public
  └─styles
    │  global.css (output for sass compiling is here).
    └─sass
      └─_variables.scss
      └─global.scss
```

_variables.scss

```
$font-text: 'lato', sans-serif;
```

global.scss

```
@use '_variables';

body {
  font-family: $font-text;
}
```

Looking at the [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import), I understand to use `@use` instead of `@import` (which works) because they are phasing it out.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's because you are not using Dart Sass which supports this feature.

Also in the documentation you will find:

> Only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the @import rule instead.

So use `@import` until `@use` is supported.

BTW, If you want to use Dart Sass, just use `sass` instead of `node-sass` and require it in the webpack config, like:

```
// ...
{
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    implementation: require('sass')
  }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Didn't know there were multiple versions.

Comment: The documentation at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use does not show the disclaimer about Dart Sass unless you click the square with the triangle inside it under the heading 

Comment: If you're reading this answer, please have a look at my answer below.  It is in addendum to this.  The rabbit hole has gotten a bit deeper in 2021.

Answer (score 5):

## Short Answer

> You can access variables, functions, and mixins from another module by writing < namespace >.< variable >, < namespace >.< function>()>, or @include < namespace >.< mixin >(). By default, the namespace is just the last component of the module’s URL.

### That means by using variables.$font-text

global.scss

```
@use '_variables';

body {
  font-family: variables.$font-text;
}
```

[SASS Documentation on Loading Members](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#loading-members)

## Long Answer

So the answer or @llobet was using `webpack` and the answer of @Jamie Marshall was using gulp file, but I was trying to use `SASS` using `Node JS` and needed a step by step guide to make it work.

Here is how I made `@use` work - Step by step guide using `Dart Sass` with `Node JS`.

##### 1. Create New Node Project

```
npm init
```

##### 2. Install Dart SASS

```
npm i sass
```

Optionally you can also install AutoPrefixer using `npm install postcss-cli autoprefixer`

##### 3. Configure NPM Script to Compile SASS

In Package.json, add script `compile:sass` to compile sass to css

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "compile:sass": "sass --watch scss:assets/css"
},
```

##### 4. Create SCSS folder and inside it create style.scss file

Above script `compile:sass` expects a folder called `scss` on the root of the project and a `.scss` file inside that folder

Paste the following inside `.scss` file

```
@use '_variables';

body {
font-family: variables.$font-text;
}
```

##### 5. Create Partial file _variables.scss

Create a partial file named `_variables.scss` on the same directory `scss` and paste the following code in it

```
$font-text: 'lato', sans-serif;
```

##### 6. Compile SASS to CSS

Run the following script inside your project's root folder to compile SASS to CSS

```
npm run compile:sass
```

Now you would see a folder named `assets` and inside it there would be a folder named `css` and inside it your `css` file would be compiled.

Comment: I was missing the `variables` qualifier.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very important update to the accepted answer by @llobert.  After hours of searching, it turns out node-sass relies on libsass which is the C++ implementation of sass.  According the docs for the libsass [repository](https://github.com/sass/libsass) this C++ implementation has been deprecated.

[image: libsass done-zo]

Okay, so you may think, as easy as installing dart-sass, however you will find the docs have fallen behind here as well.  If you go to dart-sass on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass) you'll find:

[image: dart-sass renamed]

So what you have to do now is:

```
npm install sass
```

And just in case, like myself, the reader of this is researching the whole sass affair because they are using gulp-sass:

At the bottom of the gulp-sass [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) page you will find this tid bit.

[image]

Ah, what do you know.  The default hasn't changed, but the underlying libsass libary has fallen behind due to depreciation.  Thus you must add this to your gulp file:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
sass.compiler = require('sass');
```

So long story short, there are some changes going on in the SASS world that have been drastic, but yet seemingly happened very quietly.  I hope this recount of my last few hours will save some future devs a lot of time searching till the docs get sorted out.

Comment: This renaming took place quite time ago and I am already mentioning it as 'sass' package in my answer.

Comment: @llobet - yeah, but when I looked at your answer I totally glossed over the "sass" bit.  With all the docs pointing different directions its quite a spelunk to realize your solution is correct.  Also, there's plenty of posts else were giving the wrong info, its a needle in a hey stack without the full story..  An if, like me, this sass stuff is part of a larger build, it means you also need to know how to reconcile the info gained here with the docs of other packages you might be using.