# Correct syntax for "nested" @use statements in Sass/SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I've been turning all the `@import` rules in my Sass stylesheets to the new `@use` rules as I understand they're a bit cleaner once compiled and don't end up loading the same CSS multiple times.
However, I'm having a bit of trouble working out how to, for lack of a better word, chain these `@use` rules so I can access variables and stuff through multiple files.

So, for example, I have the following setup:

*_variables.scss:*

```
$primary: #1d1d1d;
$secondary: #0f0f0f;
$light-grey: #a0a0a0;
$accent: #5DFDCB;
$white: #ffffff;
$blurple: #7289da;
```

which is `@use`d in *_defaults.scss:*

```
@use "bootstrap/grid.scss";

@use "typography";
@use "variables";
```

which I then want to `@use` in *card.scss:*

```
@use "../../styles/defaults";

.committee-role {
    color: $accent;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Is what I'm looking to do actually possible in the first place? If so, what's the syntax to set it up?

I was thinking it might be `color: defaults.variables.$accent;` but that hasn't seemed to work (I'm not sure if I'm writing it wrong or if the extension I'm using to compile it to CSS doesn't support the syntax yet...)

Is it then the same sort of syntax for using mixins from other files, too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I *think* it would just be `color: variables.$accent` since, `_defaults.scss` is already declaring the name space. I could be wrong. Have you tried that?

Comment: I've done some more digging and am beginning to get the feeling that it's not working because it *shouldn't* be working. This post from 6 months ago says that `@use` is currently only supported by dart-sass. I'm trying to do this in a React project, which is uses libsass.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474760/sass-use-not-loading-partial

Think that might be the problem!

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue today using dart-sass and found this question when searching for a solution.

Reading through the documentation, I found that the [@forward](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward) rule should be used instead of `@use` in the intermediate file.

> The rule loads the module at the given URL just like @use, but it makes the public members of the loaded module available to users of your module as though they were defined directly in your module.

So in the example files used in the original question, *_defaults.scss* would be updated to

```
@forward "variables";
```

and then the `accent` would be used as follows:

```
@use "../../styles/defaults";

.committee-role {
    color: defaults.$accent;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: That looks like it might be useful in a lot of cases, but what do you do when you want to use a variable set in _variables.scss both inside _defaults.scss *and* inside card.scss?

Comment: I'll answer that myself, with a snippet from the [official docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward/): "Those members aren’t available in your module, though—if you want that, you’ll need to write a @use rule as well. Don’t worry, it’ll only load the module once!"