# @use rule not working in gulp-sass using sublime text 3

Tags: css, sass, gulp, sublimetext3, gulp-sass

i use gulp-sass to compile my sass (SCSS) files into css. everything works but when i use @use rule of sass to include a partial it compiles the @use rule statement as it is into css instead of including that partial file code. [image of compiling @use rule using gulp-sass (doesn't work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpHGu.png)

But when i use @import rule of sass it compiles sucessfully and include that partial scss file code into css. but sass documentation don't recommend the use of @import rule so thats why i want to use @use rule
[image of compiling @import rule using gulp-sass (works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XkPb.png)

i am currently using sublime text 3 and i have researched online for the issue and the issue is with gulp-sass and the solution is to make the "atomic_save": true in sublime text user settings but that doesn't work for me either. 

[setting "atomic_save": true in sublime text under preferences -> settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YJ8J.png) 

 [setting "atomic_save": true in sublime text under preferences -> settings - syntax specific](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBun.png)

 Please Help

Comment: Have you tried using gulp-sass from the command line, and does it give the same results?

Comment: Guplp-sass does not support @use, look at gulp-dart-sass instead.  I'm on a phone but a search for those terms should find this info.  There is no ST3 setting that will make gulp-sass work.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes the windows command line gives the same result

Comment: And thank you @Mark i will try to use gulp-dart-sass, just one question as i am new to this is there any major differences between gulp-sass and gulp-dart-sass in terms of syntax or anything else? i researched online and both looks exactly similar except the gulp-dart-sass complies a little slower i think which is not a big issue for me cause the end user speed performance is not affected by it as it is compiled before deployment.

Comment: @Mark please make a quick answer, preferably with a link to `gulp-dart-sass`. Comments aren't guaranteed to be around forever. It will also save the question from potentially being a [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass @use not loading partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474760/sass-use-not-loading-partial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp-sass does not support @use, use gulp-dart-sass instead