# Error when using @use instead of @import in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Normally, I using @import for importing scss files to my main.scss file. It works in a way that I import all my files to one single file I call main.scss, then compile that file to css.
But I saw that that @import is deprecated and trying to switch to @use and @forward, but I doing something wrong...
On the image below you can see the structure of my files
[image]

And you can see at the bottom error I get. You can see how main.scss look from the image, these are other files:
mixins.scss

```
@mixin bgImage($image) {
    background: url($image);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  
  @mixin flexCenter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  @mixin overlayGradient {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      #9f40b9 42.84%,
      rgba(135, 76, 232, 0) 70.48%
    );
  }
  
  @mixin borderRadius {
    border-radius: 1rem!important;
  }
  
  @mixin transition {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  @mixin dropShadow {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #060606, -5px -5px 10px #0c0e0e!important;
  }
  
  @mixin skew($side: right, $deg: -20deg, $right: -15px, $left: -15px, $width: 30px, $bg: #fff) {
      // position: relative;
  
      &:before {
          z-index: 1;
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
  
          @if $side == right {
              right: $right;
          }
          @else if $side == left {
              left: $left;
          }
  
          display: block;
          width: $width;
          background: $bg;
          transform: skew($deg);
      }
  }
  
  @mixin respond($breakpoint) {
    @if $breakpoint == phone-mini {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 26.25em) {
        @content;
      } //420px
    }
  
    @if $breakpoint == phone {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 34.375em) {
        @content;
      } //550px
    }
  
    @if $breakpoint == phone-big {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 43.75em) {
        @content;
      } //700px
    }
  
    @if $breakpoint == tab-port {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) {
        @content;
      } //900px
    }
  
    @if $breakpoint == tab-land {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 75em) {
        @content;
      } //1200px
    }
  
    @if $breakpoint == bigtab-land {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 90.625em) {
        @content;
      } //1450px
    }
  
    @if $breakpoint == big-desktop {
      @media only screen and (min-width: 112.5em) {
        @content;
      } //1800px
    }
  }
```

index.scss (inside abstracts folder)

```
@forward '../abstracts/custom';
@forward '../abstracts/mixins';
```

base.scss

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 html {
    @include respond(tab-land) {
       //width < 1200
       font-size: 56.25%; //1 rem = 9px, 9/16 = 56.25%
    }
 
    @include respond(tab-port) {
       //width < 900
       font-size: 50%; //1 rem = 8px, 8/16 = 50%
    }
 
    @include respond(big-desktop) {
       font-size: 75%; //1 rem = 12px, 12/16 = 75%
    }
 }
 
 html {
    //This defines what 1rem is
    font-size: 62.5%; //1rem = 10px; 10px/16px = 62.5%
    // scrollbar-color: $color-primary $color-tertiary;
    // scrollbar-width: thin;
    // scrollbar-face-color: $color-primary;
    // scrollbar-track-color: $color-tertiary;
 }
 
 body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    // background-color: $color-primary;
    // background-color: $color-bodyBg;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
 
    @include respond(phone-big) {
       font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
 }
 
 button,
 input,
 label,


form,
 select {
    font-family: inherit;
 }
 
 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6,
 p,
 a {
    color: $color-text;
 }
 
 ::selection {
    background-color: $color-text;
    //    color: $white;
    color: #393939;
 }
 
 ::placeholder {
    /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: $color-text;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
 }
 
 :-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: $color-text;
 }
 
 ::-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: $color-text;
 }
 
 /* Scrollbar Styling */
 // ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 //    width: .8rem;
 // }
 
 // ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 //    background-color: $color-tertiary;
 // }
 
 // ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 //    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
 //    border-radius: 0.5rem;
 //    background: $color-secondary;
 // }
 
 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
 }
 
 li {
    list-style: none;
 }
 
 .input {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid $color-text;
    @include borderRadius;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 1.2rem 1rem;
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0.6rem;
    // color: $color-secondary;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    @include transition;
 
    &:focus-visible{
       outline: 0 !important;
    }
 
    // &:active,
    // &:focus {
    //    border: 2px solid $color-secondary;
    // }
 
    &::placeholder {
       color: $color-secondary;
       font-family: inherit;
       font-size: 1.4rem;
       font-weight: 300;
       color: rgba(#fff, 0.6);
    }
 
    &:disabled {
       opacity: 0.4;
       filter: grayscale(1);
    }
 }
 
 /* It's a custom checkbox, so it have to be used with label */
 .checkbox {
    padding: 0;
    height: initial;
    width: initial;
    margin: 1rem;
    //         display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
 
    &:focus + label::before {
       border: 2px solid $color-secondary;
       @include dropShadow;
    }
 
    &-label {
       position: relative;
       cursor: pointer;
       font-size: 1.6rem;
       text-transform: none;
       font-weight: 400;
 
       &:before {
          content: '';
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          background-color: transparent;
          border: 2px solid $color-text;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
             inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          padding: 0.8rem;
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          vertical-align: middle;
          cursor: pointer;
          margin-right: 1rem;
          margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
          border-radius: 3px;
          @include transition;
       }
    }
 
    &:checked + &-label::after {
       content: '';
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       left: 7px;
       width: 6px;
       height: 14px;
       border: solid $color-text;
       border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
       transform: rotate(45deg);
       @include transition;
    }
 
    &:checked + &-label::before {
       background-color: $color-secondary;
       @include transition;
    }
 }
 
 .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
 }
 
 .container {
    @include respond(bigtab-land) {
       padding: 0 2.5rem !important;
    }
    @include respond(phone){
       padding-inline: 1rem !important;
    }
 }
 
 .container-content {
    @include respond(bigtab-land) {
       padding: 0 3.5rem !important;
    }
 
    @include respond(phone-big) {
       padding: 0 1.5rem !important;
    }
 }
 
 .navMaxWidth {
    max-width: 140rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

index.scss (inside base folder)

```
@forward '../base/base';
```

Other files are empty for now. What I am doing wrong here? These things with @use and @forward really confusing me...

Comment: `@use` only works with Dart-Sass. You are most likely using LibSass or RubySass to compile your CSS. You'll have to upgrade whatever compiler you are using. Your SCSS isn't helpful in this question (except to know you are using `@use`). We would need to see your `package.json` instead. Also, don't worry about the `@include` deprecation if you are working on a current project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass @use not loading partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474760/sass-use-not-loading-partial)